# Prove that for any positive integer c, there are infinitely many integers x with gcd(a+bx,c)=1.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Assume gcd(a,b)=1 with a, b positive integers. Prove that for any positive integer c, there are infinitely many integers x with gcd(a+bx,c)=1.

Comment: If $c$ is even, can $x$ be all integers so that $a + bx$ is odd?

Comment: This follows immediately from Dirichlet's theorem : Because $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there exist infinite many primes of the form $a+bx$. Every such prime greater than $c$ is coprime to $c$.

Comment: Is there a way to do it perhaps using the Chinese remainder theorem and without Dirichlet's?